# Apache cambia los headers

Tags: django, apache

tengo una api en django corriendo en apache

Al momento de hacer una solicitud estos headers entran

```
T 172.70.82.247:35304 -> 172.26.2.129:80 [AP] #4
GET /login/ HTTP/1.1.
Host: api.hiringpt.com.
Connection: Keep-Alive.
accept-encoding: gzip.
X-Forwarded-For: 2800:484:3841:af00:d0b9:845f:5ba7:28b7.
CF-RAY: 859096e37f3b67b4-MIA.
X-Forwarded-Proto: https.
CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}.
sec-ch-ua: "Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121".
accept: application/json.
content-type: application/json.
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0.
authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImExODE4ZjQ0ODk0MjI1ZjQ2MWQyMmI1NjA4NDcyMDM3MTc2MGY1OWIiLCJ0eXAiOiJ.
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36.
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS".
origin: https://hiringpt.com.
sec-fetch-site: same-site.
sec-fetch-mode: cors.
sec-fetch-dest: empty.
referer: https://hiringpt.com/.
accept-language: es,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es-US;q=0.7.
priority: u=1, i.
CF-Connecting-IP: 2800:484:3841:af00:d0b9:845f:5ba7:28b7.
CDN-Loop: cloudflare.
CF-IPCountry: CO.
```

Pero al momento de entrar al endpoint los headers que entran son

```
{'Host': 'api.hiringpt.com', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip', 'X-Forwarded-For': '2800:484:3841:af00:d0b9:845f:5ba7:28b7', 'Cf-Ray': '859096e37f3b67b4-MIA', 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https', 'Cf-Visitor': '{"scheme":"https"}', 'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"macOS"', 'Origin': 'https://hiringpt.com', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Referer': 'https://hiringpt.com/', 'Accept-Language': 'es,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es-US;q=0.7', 'Priority': 'u=1, i', 'Cf-Connecting-Ip': '2800:484:3841:af00:d0b9:845f:5ba7:28b7', 'Cdn-Loop': 'cloudflare', 'Cf-Ipcountry': 'CO'}
```

por que al entrar en el servidor si entran los headers normal inclutendo el token de auth y al momento de entrar en django me los cambia, los dns los tengo distribuidos con cloudflare

Comment: Diria que te falta la cabecera "authorization: Bearer"... así sin más info poco más se te puede decir supongo.. el resto de cabeceras sí que está.  Tampoco sé si es buena idea que la hayas puesto en un sitio público, pues ahora todos la podemos usar, a menos que sea dinámica de algun modo.

Comment: @masterguru es dinamica y no esta completa, le falta el 80%, pero al momento de hacer la peticion si va, pero cuando entra a django que esta corriendo en apache como que la elimina

Comment: Mira a ver si esto tiene que ver con lo tuyo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387516/authorization-header-missing-in-django-rest-framework-is-apache-to-blame